# a beginner question on XSLT

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, saxon

I just started learning XSLT,now I am following some on-line tutorial of it,and I just have a simple question now:

suppose we have a original xml file,do we need to write a XSLT Stylesheet to go with it,or do we just simply pass the xml file into some software like Stylus Studio(Saxon Engine),then it will do all these things automatically for us?

Sorry for the mis clarification.I need to convert this .svg file to a pdf,I am just now at the beginning of the development,so really confused about the first step.Also,I would like to know,if my initial input is a .svg file,do I have to explicitly transform it into an .xml before I can start using XSLT?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on what are you're trying to do. What do you expect from the XSLT Stylesheet, what transformation should happen?

Comment: This question is a little unclear. What is the result you are expecting? What are you using the XSLT for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Sorry for the mis clarification.I need to convert this .svg file to a pdf,I am just now at the beginning of the development,so really confused about the first step.Also,I would like to know,if my initial input is a .svg file,do I have to explicitly transform it into an .xml before I can start using XSLT?

An SVG file *is* an XML file in the SVG namespace. Whether or not you need to transform that XML depends on how you're going to use it. If you were going to do a batch print using something like Inkscape (an SVG editor), you wouldn't.

If you are going to use something like XSL-FO, you would. The answer by @Zoltan Hamori is kind of misleading. You can use saxon to perform an XSLT transform (creating the XSL-FO), but you will still need an XSL-FO processor to create the PDF from the XSL-FO.

Zoltan mentions FOP (Apache Formatting Objects Processor), but he makes it sound like FOP and XSL-FO are the same; they're not. His code example is an XSL-FO table (XML in the `fo` namespace). You would need a processor such as FOP, RenderX, Antenna House, etc. to create the PDF from the XSL-FO.

Basically what you need is:

1. XML input (this would be your SVG file)
2. XSLT transform to create the XSL-FO.
3. XSL-FO processor to create the PDF from the XSL-FO

Learning the XSL-FO at the same time you're learning XSLT is going to be tough, but I will show you two ways to output an SVG in a PDF.

The first way is to reference the SVG file using `fo:external-graphic`.

The second way is to embed the SVG XML directly into the XSL-FO using `fo:instream-foreign-object`.

Since the XML input is the SVG XML, I would go with the second option. However, I'm not sure what effect this has on processing time and which way would be more efficient.

I've shown an example below. Since I showed both ways to output an SVG, this will create a 2 page PDF. Each page will have the SVG graphic.

**Notes**

- For testing, I used an example SVG file that came with Inkscape. (I removed most of the SVG XML from the XSL-FO output because it's pretty big.)
- For my XSLT processor, I used Saxon-HE 9.2.0.6.
- For my FO processor, I used Apache FOP Version 0.95 (although I much prefer RenderX).

**Also**

- Both Saxon-HE and Apache FOP are free.
- If you give me your email, I can send you the SVG file I used along with the full XSL-FO output. I can also send you the PDF that was created.

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- 
    This is an "identity" template.
    It copies whatever node from input to the output without changing it. 
    Learn it. Use it. Love it. -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page">
          <fo:region-body/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <fo:block>
            <!-- This is the first way to output an SVG; by referencing the graphic. -->
            <fo:external-graphic src="test.svg"/>
            <!-- This is the second way to output an SVG; by outputting the SVG XML directly. -->
            <fo:instream-foreign-object>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:instream-foreign-object>
          </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSL-FO** (created by Saxon from SVG input and XSL stylesheet)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page">
         <fo:region-body/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:block>
            <fo:external-graphic src="test.svg"/>
            <fo:instream-foreign-object>
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                    version="1.1"
                    width="595.99438"
                    height="491.50516"
                    id="svg2675">
                <!-- CONTENT REMOVED FOR STACKOVERFLOW.COM EXAMPLE -->
              </svg>
            </fo:instream-foreign-object>
         </fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much,DevNull,could you please email me your svg?Thanks.My email is thuderfan@live.com.

Comment: Also,I have a question,will the XSL stylesheet and XSL-FO you provided work with all the svg file or will it only work with your specific svg file?thanks

Comment: @Robert - The XSL stylesheet should work with all svg files. I would remove the `fo:external-graphic` though. If you did want to use `fo:external-graphic` instead of `fo:instream-foreign-object`, you'd have to pass the svg filename as a parameter. I will email you the svg and the full XSL-FO file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert data to PDF, you may use XSL:FO/FOP. You need a FOP template which is an xsl file and that can be converted to PDF. This xsl file can reference to XML, external objects like image files or you can use freemarker/velocity to put data into the XSL template.

You can find more info:
http://www.treebuilder.de/svg/extentSVG/artikel/tut.html

If you use FOP tags, you can reference to the SVG file like:

```
   <fo:table text-align="left" table-layout="fixed"
                                      background-image="SVG_file.svg">
```

I think it is possible to add the svg file to saxon as a parameter

Comment: suppose now I am going to use Saxon in java to do this conversion,shall I understand you as the svg file as the input xml and the said FOP template as the xml in the Saxon command?

Answer (score -1):

Svg is an Xml-File. So, you could start writing your own XSLT stylesheet to transform it into the desired format.

But a quick search on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=de&lr=lang_en&tbo=1&prmdo=1&as_qdr=all&tbs=lr%3alang_1en&q=svg+to+pdf+converter&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) showed me a lot of programs that can do this conversion for you.

Comment: No, if you only want to convert an svg to pdf, try to use a search-engine (e.g. Google) to search for programs that can do this conversion.