# how to add pdf file to xslt as html

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:template match="tos">
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4">
            <fo:region-body/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block-container>
                <fo:block>Hello W3Schools</fo:block>    
                </fo:block>
            </fo:block-container>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
                <fo:block><fox:external-document content-type="pdf" src="/system/attachments/documents/sample.pdf" width="425" height="355"/> //how to add pdf file like this
</fo:root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I wanna a display pdf file like html in xslt page
actual if i added attachment then it will display below of my xslt tag

Comment: I tired this but the pdf is not displaying

Comment: Consider this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4129055/3617262 - I'd venture that you're only accounting for "part 2" of the solution (using XSL to generate XSL-FO) but you still need to feed all of that into an XSL-FO processor to have an actual PDF generated.