# How to generate Bar Charts in PDF Documents with XSLT and Apache FOP

Tags: java, xml, xslt, charts, apache-fop

I'm looking for a method to generate a *Bar Chart* in XSLT using Java Apache FOP.

I'm trying to generate bar chart with below XML and XSLT but its generating empty .PDF file without any chart?

**data.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sales>
 <region>
  <title>Eastern Region Quarterly Sales (Second/'04)</title>
  <key1 area="New York Area">.95</key1>
  <key2 area="Virginia Area">.89</key2>
  <key3 area="Maryland Area">.67</key3>
  <key4 area="Connecticut Area">.65</key4>
  <key5 area="Delaware Area">.45</key5>
 </region>
</sales>
```

**bar.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="sales">
        <svg width="650" height="500">
            <g id="axis" transform="translate(0 500) scale(1 -1)">
                <line id="axis-y" x1="30" y1="20" x2="30" y2="450" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
                <line id="axis-x" x1="30" y1="20" x2="460" y2="20" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
            </g>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="region" />
        </svg>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="region">
        <g id="bars" transform="translate(30 479) scale(1 -430)">
            <rect x="30" y="0" width="50" height="{key1}" style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0" />
            <rect x="100" y="0" width="50" height="{key2}" style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0" />
            <rect x="170" y="0" width="50" height="{key3}" style="fill:rgb(255,255,0);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0" />
            <rect x="240" y="0" width="50" height="{key4}" style="fill:rgb(0,255,255);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0" />
            <rect x="310" y="0" width="50" height="{key5}" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0" />
        </g>
        <g id="scale" transform="translate(29 60)">
            <text id="scale1" x="0px" y="320px" style="text-anchor:end;fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:10;font-family:Arial">$25K</text>
            <text id="scale2" x="0px" y="215px" style="text-anchor:end;fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:10;font-family:Arial">$50K</text>
            <text id="scale3" x="0px" y="107.5px" style="text-anchor:end;fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:10;font-family:Arial">$75K</text>
            <text id="scale4" x="0px" y="0px" style="text-anchor:end;fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:10;font-family:Arial">$100K</text>
        </g>
        <g id="key">
            <rect id="key1" x="430" y="80" width="25" height="15" style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
            <rect id="key2" x="430" y="100" width="25" height="15" style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
            <rect id="key3" x="430" y="120" width="25" height="15" style="fill:rgb(255,255,0);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
            <rect id="key5" x="430" y="140" width="25" height="15" style="fill:rgb(0,255,255);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
            <rect id="key4" x="430" y="160" width="25" height="15" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
        </g>
        <text id="key1-text" x="465px" y="92px" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:18;font-family:Arial">
            <xsl:value-of select="key1/@area" />
        </text>
        <text id="key2-text" x="465px" y="112px" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:18;font-family:Arial">
            <xsl:value-of select="key2/@area" />
        </text>
        <text id="key3-text" x="465px" y="132px" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:18;font-family:Arial">
            <xsl:value-of select="key3/@area" />
        </text>
        <text id="key4-text" x="465px" y="152px" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:18;font-family:Arial">
            <xsl:value-of select="key4/@area" />
        </text>
        <text id="key5-text" x="465px" y="172px" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:18;font-family:Arial">
            <xsl:value-of select="key5/@area" />
        </text>
        <g id="title">
            <text x="325px" y="20px" style="text-anchor:middle;fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:24;font-family:Arial">
                <xsl:value-of select="title" />
            </text>
        </g>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting empty pdf and I tried to generate svg file also - It also not showing any graph. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You could create and embed an SVG in the XSL-FO using `fo:instream-foreign-object`. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121501/a-beginner-question-on-xslt/4129055#4129055 That isn't exactly what you're trying to do because in that answer the SVG already exists. You would have to create the SVG in the XSLT to use in the `fo:instream-foreign-object`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! How to create an SVG chart using xml or xslt?

Comment: Daniel Haley's suggestion is good. Create the coordinates of the _Bar Chart's_ bars in XSLT, output them as SVG and then use them in a `fo:instream-foreign-object` in Apache FOP to embed them in the PDF. This sounds like a nice little exercise, I'd upvote if you'll post a working example here.

Comment: @zx485 - Added a working example in my answer. :-)

Comment: @DanielHaley: Looks nice, hence I upvoted it :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create and embed an SVG in the XSL-FO using [`fo:instream-foreign-object`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslfo20/#fo_instream-foreign-object).

Since you're wanting to use XSLT and FOP, I'm assuming you have input data in XML. (If not, maybe XSLT and FOP aren't the right tools for the job?)

So the XSLT would create the XSL-FO and the embedded SVG from your XML input. FOP would create the PDF from the XSL-FO.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<list>
    <fruit>
        <type>Apples</type>
        <qty>5</qty>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>
        <type>Oranges</type>
        <qty>2</qty>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>
        <type>Bananas</type>
        <qty>7</qty>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>
        <type>Peaches</type>
        <qty>9</qty>
    </fruit>
</list>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
          <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="list">
    <fo:block>Example embedded SVG:</fo:block>
    <fo:block space-before="4pt">
      <fo:instream-foreign-object>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="420" height="150">
          <title id="title">List of Fruit</title>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="fruit">
            <xsl:sort select="type" order="ascending" data-type="text"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </svg>
      </fo:instream-foreign-object>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fruit">
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="((position() - 1) * 20) + (position() * 5 - 5)"/>
    <g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <rect width="{qty * 10}" height="20" y="{$y}"/>
      <text x="100" y="{$y + 10}" dy=".35em">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(qty,' ',type)"/>
      </text>
    </g>    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSL-FO Output**

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
         <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:block>Example embedded SVG:</fo:block>
         <fo:block space-before="4pt">
            <fo:instream-foreign-object>
               <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="420" height="150">
                  <title id="title">List of Fruit</title>
                  <g>
                     <rect width="50" height="20" y="0"/>
                     <text x="100" y="10" dy=".35em">5 Apples</text>
                  </g>
                  <g>
                     <rect width="70" height="20" y="25"/>
                     <text x="100" y="35" dy=".35em">7 Bananas</text>
                  </g>
                  <g>
                     <rect width="20" height="20" y="50"/>
                     <text x="100" y="60" dy=".35em">2 Oranges</text>
                  </g>
                  <g>
                     <rect width="90" height="20" y="75"/>
                     <text x="100" y="85" dy=".35em">9 Peaches</text>
                  </g>
               </svg>
            </fo:instream-foreign-object>
         </fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

The rendered PDF would be a single 8.5" x 11" page with the following content:

[image]

Notes:

- I used Saxon-HE to do the XSLT transform. Saxon is an XSLT 3.0 processor, so if you decide to use it you aren't stuck with the limitations of XSLT 1.0. I only used XSLT 1.0 because this is a very basic example.
- I used FOP version 2.1 (that's included with oXygen XML Editor) to process the XSL-FO to create the PDF output.

---

**UPDATED XSLT FROM MODIFIED QUESTION:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
          <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body"> 
          <fo:block>
            <fo:instream-foreign-object>
              <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:instream-foreign-object>
          </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sales">
    <svg width="650" height="500">
      <g id="axis" transform="translate(0 500) scale(1 -1)">
        <line id="axis-y" x1="30" y1="20" x2="30" y2="450" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
        <line id="axis-x" x1="30" y1="20" x2="460" y2="20" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
      </g>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="region" />
    </svg>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="region">
    <g id="bars" transform="translate(30 479) scale(1 -430)">
      <rect x="30" y="0" width="50" height="{key1}" style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0" />
      <rect x="100" y="0" width="50" height="{key2}" style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0" />
      <rect x="170" y="0" width="50" height="{key3}" style="fill:rgb(255,255,0);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0" />
      <rect x="240" y="0" width="50" height="{key4}" style="fill:rgb(0,255,255);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0" />
      <rect x="310" y="0" width="50" height="{key5}" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:0" />
    </g>
    <g id="scale" transform="translate(29 60)">
      <text id="scale1" x="0px" y="320px" style="text-anchor:end;fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:10;font-family:Arial">$25K</text>
      <text id="scale2" x="0px" y="215px" style="text-anchor:end;fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:10;font-family:Arial">$50K</text>
      <text id="scale3" x="0px" y="107.5px" style="text-anchor:end;fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:10;font-family:Arial">$75K</text>
      <text id="scale4" x="0px" y="0px" style="text-anchor:end;fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:10;font-family:Arial">$100K</text>
    </g>
    <g id="key">
      <rect id="key1" x="430" y="80" width="25" height="15" style="fill:rgb(255,0,0);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
      <rect id="key2" x="430" y="100" width="25" height="15" style="fill:rgb(0,255,0);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
      <rect id="key3" x="430" y="120" width="25" height="15" style="fill:rgb(255,255,0);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
      <rect id="key5" x="430" y="140" width="25" height="15" style="fill:rgb(0,255,255);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
      <rect id="key4" x="430" y="160" width="25" height="15" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke:rgb(0,0,0);stroke-width:1" />
    </g>
    <text id="key1-text" x="465px" y="92px" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:18;font-family:Arial">
      <xsl:value-of select="key1/@area" />
    </text>
    <text id="key2-text" x="465px" y="112px" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:18;font-family:Arial">
      <xsl:value-of select="key2/@area" />
    </text>
    <text id="key3-text" x="465px" y="132px" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:18;font-family:Arial">
      <xsl:value-of select="key3/@area" />
    </text>
    <text id="key4-text" x="465px" y="152px" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:18;font-family:Arial">
      <xsl:value-of select="key4/@area" />
    </text>
    <text id="key5-text" x="465px" y="172px" style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:18;font-family:Arial">
      <xsl:value-of select="key5/@area" />
    </text>
    <g id="title">
      <text x="325px" y="20px" style="text-anchor:middle;fill:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:24;font-family:Arial">
        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
      </text>
    </g>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PDF Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! - I tried your example - it works. I tried another example of a bar chart but I'm getting empty pdf. I've updated the original post with sample XML and XSLT. Can you tell what I'm missing?

Comment: @learngroovy - I would think your PDF was empty because you didn't create any XSL-FO (unless you're trying to get FOP to create a PDF just from SVG which I'm not sure is possible (but I don't use FOP often either)). To get your stylesheet to work I added a template to output the XSL-FO (`match="/"`) and also added the svg namespace (`xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`) to xsl:stylesheet. Please see my edit.

Comment: Hi Daniel - I liked your example, I've similar requirement - How to create bar and line chart with dynamic data? I'm looking chart like this https://peltiertech.com/images/2009-11/BarLine_ColumnLine.png It would be really appreciated if you can reuse the same example to populate data in a dynamic way and generate line chart. Thanks.

Comment: @mark - my first example is fairly dynamic in the sense that most of the values are being generated. For example, I could add more `fruit` and not have to make any changes to the stylesheet. What I would recommend is manually create a sample svg chart and then figure out how to generate that svg in your stylesheet using your input xml.